# how to select all rows in tibble with chr ("IBM")

Tags: r

How can I get all rows where the variable Ticker equals "AA". The data structure is a tibble.  My data is stored in rebate data and looks like

```
 A tibble: 1,048,575 x 7
   Date       Ticker CUR         CON REBATERATE FEERATE AVAILABLE
   <chr>      <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 09/25/2017 A      USD     1715006      0.101   1.06   10000000
 2 09/25/2017 AA     USD   251962528      0.494   0.666   4900000
 3 09/25/2017 AAAP   USD   212212690     -6.28    7.44     300000
 4 09/25/2017 AABA   USD   278946664      0.674   0.486  10000000
```

. 
I would like to get the row

```
2 09/25/2017 AA     USD   251962528      0.494   0.666   4900000
```

I tried the code:

```
xx<-filter(rebatedata, Ticker == "AA")
```

and get the error:

```
Error in filter(rebatedata, Ticker == "AA") : object 'Ticker' not found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion.
```

Comment: It should work. Can you try `filter(rebatedata, as.character(Ticker) == "AA")` or if it doesn't work add a reproducible example `dput` ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue would arise if the package `dplyr` is not loaded.  There is a base R `filter` (from `stats`) which has a different behavior (`?stats::filter`)

> Applies linear filtering to a univariate time series or to each series separately of a multivariate time series.

If we do the `filter` on a fresh `R` session with no packages loaded

```
filter(iris, Species == 'setosa')
```

> Error in filter(iris, Species == "setosa") : object 'Species' not
>   found

or

```
stats::filter(iris, Species == 'setosa')
```

> Error in stats::filter(iris, Species == "setosa") :    object
>   'Species' not found

---

Now, if we load the package `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(iris, Species == "setosa") 
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#...
```